# How to stop a loop?

Tags: python

```
def sum_div(x, y):
    for k in range(x,y+1):
        for z in range(x,y+1):
            sx = 0
            sy = 0
            for i in range(1, k+1):
                if k % i == 0:
                    sx += i
            for j in range(1, z+1):
                if z % j == 0:
                    sy += j
            if sx == sy and k!= z:
                 print "(", k ,",", z, ")"

x = input("Dati x : ")
y = input("Dati y : ")
sum_div(x, y)
```

How do I stop the looping if the value of `z == y`?

The loops print a pair of numbers in a range from `x` to `y`, but when it hit the `y` value the loop prints a reverse pair of numbers that I don't need it to.

Comment: Why does your for loop range specifically include y, and what do you expect `while y` to do?

Comment: Whereabouts and in which loop do you want to break?

Comment: Perhaps it might be easier to explain what you are trying to do with the function as a whole. To me this seems like an  [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and there might be a better way to solve it.

Comment: The code is working well, the only problem is when i'm printing the results ( 10 , 17 ) ( 14 , 15 ) ( 14 , 23 ) ( 15 , 14 ) ( 15 , 23 ) ( 16 , 25 ) I need to stop here, because this is going on reverse ( 17 , 10 ) ( 23 , 14 ) ( 23 , 15 ) ( 25 , 16 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're think you are asking for is the [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-break_stmt) command, but what you're actually looking for is removal of duplication.

Your program lacks some clarity. For instance:

```
for i in range(1, k+1): 
    if k % i == 0:  
        sx += i
for j in range(1, z+1):
    if z % j == 0:
        sy += j
```

These two things are doing essentially the same thing, which can be written more cleanly with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (in the REPL):

```
>>> def get_divisors(r: int) -> list:
...     return [i if r % i == 0 else 0 for i in range(1, r+1)]
... 
... 
>>> get_divisors(4)
>>> [1, 2, 0, 4]

>>> sum(get_divisors(4))
>>> 7
```

Your line:

```
while y:
```

... will infinitely loop if you find a match. You should just remove it. `while y` means "while y is true", and any value there will evaluate as true.

This reduces your program to the following:

```
def get_divisors(r: int) -> list:
    return [i if r % i == 0 else 0 for i in range(1, r+1)]

def sum_div(x, y):
    for k in range(x,y+1): 
        sum_of_x_divisors = sum(get_divisors(k))  # Note this is moved here to avoid repeating work.
        for z in range(x,y+1):
            sum_of_y_divisors = sum(get_divisors(z))
            if sum_of_x_divisors == sum_of_y_divisors and k!= z:
                print("({},{})".format(k, z))
```

Testing this in the REPL it seems correct based on the logic of the code:

```
>>> sum_div(9,15)
(14,15)
(15,14)
>>> sum_div(21, 35)
(21,31)
(31,21)
(33,35)
(35,33)
```

But it's possible that for `sum_div(9,15)` you want only one of `(14,15)` and `(15,14)`. However, this has nothing to do with breaking your loop, but the fact that what you're attempting to do has two valid values when `k` and `z` don't equal each other. This is demonstrated by the second test case, where `(33,35)` is a repeated value, but if you broke the for loop on `(21,31)` you would not get that second set of values.

One way we can account for this is by reordering when work is done:

```
def sum_div(x, y):
    result_set = set()  # Sets cannot have duplicate values
    for k in range(x,y+1): 
        sum_of_x_divisors = sum(get_divisors(k))
        for z in range(x,y+1):
            sum_of_y_divisors = sum(get_divisors(z))
            if sum_of_x_divisors == sum_of_y_divisors and k!= z:
                result_set.add(tuple(sorted((k,z))))  # compile the result set by sorting it and casting to a tuple, so duplicates are implicitly removed.
    for k, z in result_set:  # Print result set after it's been compiled
        print("({},{})".format(k, z))
```

And we see a correct result:

```
>>> sum_div(9,15)
(14,15)
>>> sum_div(21,35)
(21,31)
(33,35)
```

Or, the test case you provided in comments. Note the lack of duplicates:

```
>>> sum_div(10,25)
(16,25)
(14,15)
(15,23)
(10,17)
(14,23)
```

Some takeaways:

- Break out functions that are doing the same thing so you can reason more easily about it.
- Name your variables in a human-readable format so that we, the readers of your code (which includes you) understands what is going on.
- Don't use loops unless you're actually looping over something. `for`, `while`, etc. only need to be used if you're planning on going over a list of things.
- When asking questions, be sure to always include test input, expected output and what you're actually getting back.
- The current best-practice for `print`ing strings is to use the [`.format()` function](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#formatstrings), to make it really clear what you're printing.

Comment: Thank's for answer but the thing is that I don't need the reverse one (14,15)
(15,14) I got the same output, what I need is to stop looping when it comes to print the reverse one's ...

Comment: See my update. You do *not* need to stop looping, you need to somehow ignore that value: `sum_div(21,35)` will stop looping *too soon* if you simply break... unless you just are trying to find one solution. This is *why* you need to provide input values and expected outputs: the question you're asking above is not the solution you're actually looking for.

Comment: @FrederickCastello Updated my answer again to account for your issue, which is really one of accumulation, not loop breaking.

Comment: Here is my output all that is after (16, 25) is useless, why I can't stop there ?
`Dati x : 10
Dati y : 25
( 10 , 17 )
( 14 , 15 )
( 15 , 14 )
( 16 , 25 )
( 17 , 10 )
( 23 , 14 )
( 25 , 16 )`.

Comment: Note the sequence `( 14 , 15 ) ( 15 , 14 ) ( 16 , 25 )`. If you stop after this last element, the previous two elements are *still* repeats. You're not looking to stop the loop, you're looking to prevent duplicates. Also note that `( 23, 14 )` comes *after* `( 16 , 25 )`, so breaking your loop before then means you miss out on that valid result. I encourage you to refresh and look at how I account for this in my solution, @FrederickCastello

Comment: Did that work? Don't forget to upvote any solutions or comments that were clarifying and helpful to you. I see you're pretty new here: doing that, and 'accepting' an answer will help you get quick, detailed responses in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The `break` command will break out of the loop. So a line like this:

```
if (z == y):
    break
```

should do what you want.

Comment: It will depend where you put it, as it will only break out of the inner-most loop.

Comment: The only place where loop brake can be is before print "(", k ,",", z, ")"